# Mockito (How to correctly mock nested objects)

Tags: mockito, powermock, spring-test, powermockito

I have this next class:

```
@Service
public class BusinessService {
    @Autowired
    private RedisService redisService;
    
    private void count() {
        String redisKey = "MyKey";
        AtomicInteger counter = null;
        if (!redisService.isExist(redisKey))
            counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
        else
            counter = redisService.get(redisKey, AtomicInteger.class);

        try {
            counter.incrementAndGet();
            redisService.set(redisKey, counter, false);
            logger.info(String.format("Counter incremented by one. Current counter = %s", counter.get()));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            logger.severe(String.format("Failed to increment counter."));
        }
    }


    // Remaining code
}
```

and this this my RedisService.java class

```
@Service
public class RedisService {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisService.class);

    @Autowired
    private RedisConfig redisConfig;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        try {
            String redisURL = redisConfig.getUrl();
            logger.info("Connecting to Redis at " + redisURL);
            syncCommands = RedisClient.create(redisURL).connect().sync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception connecting to Redis: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    
    public boolean isExist(String redisKey) {
        return syncCommands.exists(new String[] { redisKey }) == 1 ? true : false;
    }

    public <T extends Serializable> void set(String key, T object, boolean convertObjectToJson) throws JsonProcessingException {
        if (convertObjectToJson)
            syncCommands.set(key, writeValueAsString(object));
        else
            syncCommands.set(key, String.valueOf(object));
    }
    // Remaining code
}
```

and this is my test class

```
@Mock
private RedisService redisService;

@Spy
@InjectMocks
BusinessService businessService = new BusinessService();

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        Whitebox.invokeMethod(businessService, "count");
    // Remaining code
}
```

my problem is the counter always equals to one in logs when running tests

> Counter incremented by one. Current counter = 1(printed 50 times)

and it should print:

> Counter incremented by one. Current counter = 1
>
> Counter incremented by one. Current counter = 2
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> Counter incremented by one. Current counter = 50

this means the Redis mock always passed as a new instance to BusinessService in each method call inside each loop, so how I can force this behavior to become only one instance used always for Redis inside the test method ??

***Note:* Above code is just a sample to explain my problem, but it's not a complete code.**

Comment: Your conclusion that a new RedisService is somehow created in each iteration is wrong. The problem is that it is a mock object for which you haven’t set any behaviours, so it responds with default values for each method call (null for objects, false for bools, 0 for ints etc)

Comment: Yes, in your case every time you create new counter `counter = new AtomicInteger(0);` and `counter.incrementAndGet();` - as result counter equals 1.

Comment: @Lesiak So any idea of how i can set behaviours for RedisService when mockito create a new instances?

Comment: @borino yes, because RedisService instance created by Mockito instantiated each time in the loop (so it's not just one instance by test method, but a new instance for each iterate in the loop in same test method)

Comment: @mibrahim.iti Use Mockito.when

Comment: @Lesiak But Mockito.when could add a restriction for creating new instances? I mean if I could use it to make sure only one instance created? because I can't pass this instance in any constructor and it only be discovered by Mockito.

Comment: You pass redisService mock to businessService (by using InjectMocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion that a new `RedisService` is somehow created in each iteration is wrong.

The problem is that it is a mock object for which you haven’t set any behaviours, so it responds with default values for each method call (null for objects, false for bools, 0 for ints etc).

You need to use `Mockito.when` to set behaviour on your mocks.

There is some additional complexity caused by the fact that:

- you run the loop multiple times, and behaviour of the mocks differ between first and subsequent iterations
- you create cached object in method under test. I used doAnswer to capture it.
- You need to use doAnswer().when() instead of when().thenAnswer as `set` method returns void
- and finally, atomicInt variable is modified from within the lambda. I made it a field of the class.
- As the atomicInt is modified each time, I again used thenAnswer instead of thenReturn for `get` method.

```
class BusinessServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private RedisService redisService;
    
    @InjectMocks
    BusinessService businessService = new BusinessService();

    AtomicInteger atomicInt = null;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        // given
        Mockito.when(redisService.isExist("MyKey"))
                .thenReturn(false)
                .thenReturn(true);

        Mockito.doAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> {
            atomicInt = invocation.getArgument(1);
            return null;
        }).when(redisService).set(eq("MyKey"), any(AtomicInteger.class), eq(false));

        Mockito.when(redisService.get("MyKey", AtomicInteger.class))
               .thenAnswer(invocation -> atomicInt);

        // when
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            Whitebox.invokeMethod(businessService, "count");
        }
        // Remaining code
    }
}
```

Having said that, I still find your code questionable.

- You store AtomicInteger in Redis cache (by serializing it to String). This class is designed to be used by multiple threads in a process, and the threads using it the same counter need to share the same instance. By serializing it and deserializing on get, you are getting multiple instances of the (conceptually) same counter, which, to my eyes, looks like a bug.
- smaller issue: You shouldn't normally test private methods
- 2 small ones: there is no need to instantiate the field annotated with @InjectMocks. You don't need @Spy as well.

Comment: First, I would like to thank you for your answer. second, it's important for me to test this private method but as you wrote "It's a smaller issue :)", about "@Spy" Unfortunately I got an error without using it when I verify the times calling of count method using "verify with times" and exception is "org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException" so obviously I must use "@Spy" annotation. For RedisService class you suggest then to use synchronized so I keep methods inside that class thread-safe, correct?

Comment: 1. If you need to verify the method call count, @sy is indeed required. 2. In a hindsight, I think you might be better off to introduce CacheService interface, implement it in RedisService for prod, and create a new InMemoryCacheService for tests (Instead of a mock). 3. No, I don't mean synchronization in RedisService. I mean I am puzzled why you are storing AtomicInteger in Redis instead of simple int. If you rely on it being AtomicInteger, that might need another look (for the reasons described in the original answer). I don't have the context of your entire app, though.

Comment: Ok, if you can share a link with me which explains the idea of implementing and InMemoryCacheService for testing it will be great. and I really used AtomicInteger because I finally need to pass a wrapper class to RedisService, so I used AtomicInteger instead of Integer to use the auto-increment functionality inside it, I know it's not a big thing to do this with normal Integer, but I think you are right, there is no need to use it and I can use Integer wrapper class instead. Finally, I would like to thank you so much for your time in answering my question and replying to comments too.

Comment: Simply create an interface `CacheService` (with methods isExist, set, and get). Implement it in RedisService. Now, create new class InMemoryCacheService and also implement CacheService, and implement same methods, using HashMap (set puts to hashMap etc). In your BusinessService, use the interface CacheService, not the concrete RedisService implementation.

Comment: Ah, got you, ok thanks, it looks like making a stub of caching service.

Comment: Yep, I think a stub is the precise term for that